# Is the value of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(C_k)^n}$ known?

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

I posted the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2799068/is-the-value-of-sum-limits-k-1%e2%88%9e-frac1c-kn-known before on mathstackexchange but realised that it might be more appropriate for mathoverflow after seeing the answer.

> Is the value of the sum $a_n:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(C_k)^n}$ known for $n \geq 1$, where $C_k= \dfrac{1}{k+1} \dbinom{2k}{k}$ are the Catalan numbers?

In the mathstackexchange thread it was shown that $a_1= 1+\frac{4\pi}{9\sqrt{3}}$ and that calculating $a_2$ might be more complicated.

Comment: I think the following is plausible. GIven a sequence $c_0, c_1,\dots$ of complex numbers for which the sum $\sum c_k$ is absolutely convergent, the sum $\sum_{k\geq 0}c_k^n$ has a closed form expression (for any reasonable definition of "closed form") for all integers $n\geq 1$ if and only if $\sum c_kx^k$ is a rational function.

Comment: What about $c_k = \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$?

Comment: @AchimKrause You are right, my statement needs to be modified.

Answer (score 8):

It can be written using a hypergeometric function

$${\mbox{$_{n+1}$F$_n$}\left(1,3,\ldots,3;\,\frac32,\ldots,\frac32;\,{\frac{1}{4^n}}\right)}$$

I don't know if further simplification is possible.

EDIT: As requested, here is some elaboration.  By definition, this generalized hypergeometric function $f$ is

$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(1)_k \left((3)_k\right)^n}{k!\; \left((3/2)_k\right)^n} (1/4)^{nk}$$
using the pochhammer symbols $$(z)_k = \Gamma(z+k)/\Gamma(z)$$
Thus $(1)_k = k!$, $(3)_k = (k+2)!/2$, $$(3/2)_k =\frac{\Gamma(3/2+k)}{\Gamma(3/2)} = \prod_{j=1}^{k} \left(\frac{2j+1}{2}\right) = \frac{(2k+1)!}{k!\; 4^k}$$ and

$$ f = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(k+2)! k! }{2\;(2k+1)!}\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(C_{k+1})^n}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Use the [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html) of the generalized hypergeometric function in terms of pochhammer symbols, convert to factorials, simplify using the equation $$\dfrac{\Gamma(3/2+k)}{\Gamma(3/2)} = \frac{(2k+1)!}{k!\; 4^k}$$

Comment: Sorry, your comment is not clear to me though I am PhD for ages. Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: Please start from the convertion of the hypergeometric function  to factorials, extending your answer. TIA.

Comment: Maple finds it for concrete $n$ up to 15 on my comp.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{C_n^2}$ is a generating function then it satisfies the differential equation 
$$z^2(z-16)f''(z)+5z^2f'(z)+4(z-1)f(z)+4=0$$
with initial conditions $f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)=1$. Solving this leads to
$$a_2=f(1).$$

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer? According Maple, the general solution of $z^2(z-16)f''(z)+5z^2f'(z)+4(z-1)+4=0$ is $$f \left( z \right) =-4096\, \left( z-16 \right) ^{-3}-{\frac {409600}{
3\, \left( z-16 \right) ^{4}}}+128\, \left( z-16 \right) ^{-2}-16\,
 \left( 3\,z-48 \right) ^{-1}-1/4\,{\frac {{\it \_C1}}{ \left( z-16
 \right) ^{4}}}-{\frac {\ln  \left( z \right) z \left( {z}^{3}-64\,{z}
^{2}+1536\,z-16384 \right) }{ \left( z-16 \right) ^{4}}}+{\it \_C2}
. $$ The function is singular at $z=0$.

Comment: Also up to Maple (the code on demand), the right limit of $f'(z)$ at $z=0$ is $-\infty$.

Comment: @user64494: I am so sorry, I missed the term $f(z)$ from $4(z-1)f(z)$.

Comment: Can you  base your modified answer?

Comment: What do you? I don't understand.

Comment: You answer is completely unbased and unclear to me. Please, elaborate is. In particular,  please explain why $a_2=f(1)$. Maple produces a complicated expression  for the general solution of $z^2(z-16)f''(z)+5z^2f'(z)+4(z-1)f(z)+4=0$ in terms of integrals of the  Legendre functions (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_function).